# How can I embed Lua in Java?

Tags: java, lua

Is LuaJava a must for this? Or can I embed Lua into Java without it?

Comment: I'm guessing that you'd prefer a pure-Java implementation of Lua (instead of LuaJava which uses native bits)?  Or are you just looking for any alternative implementation?

Comment: A pure java implementation of LUA simply does not exist, and probably will never exist.  It is a "C" project, and porting *all* that C to code java would be a huge undertaking, and I doubt the LUA authors see much benefit to that.

Comment: @deltamind106 actually most of the work is already done, about 10 years ago I [ported the entire Lua 5.1.4 package to C#](https://github.com/Myndale/KopiLua) (and yes, it was a huge undertaking). A port from that to Java would, I imagine, be considerably easier.

Answer (score 30):

LuaJ is easy to embed in Java.  I did have to change a few lines of their source to get it to work how I expected (it didn't require the IO library automatically).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/

Comment: I'm having a similar problem using Kahlua from IntelliJ. I am brand new to Lua and getting tripped up over an error, "attempted index of non-table" whenever I call "io.read()". I tried to require "io" but that doesn't work. Help?

Comment: Does anyone compare the implementation of luaj and luajava?

Answer (score 12):

Try also [kahlua](http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/) and [Mochalua](http://code.google.com/p/mochalua/).

Comment: Kahlua now located [on github](https://github.com/krka/kahlua2), but not updated since 2013.  Mochalua appears to have never been migrated off of Google Code, and is now archived; there are 4 versions on github, but none have been touched since 2015 and all just have the original 7 commits from the Google Code version from 2008-12-08.

Answer (score 2):

There is http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/manual.html, but essentially lua is more suitable for integration with C. There are a bunch of other scripting languages with good java integration around though. Consider groovy, jruby or jython for starters.

Comment: in this case I am stuck with lua otherwise I would go with jython being a python fan boy

Comment: To embed Jython is trivial, if that helps :P

Answer (score 2):

Lua is a C library, you can embed it in Java but you'll have to interface the java virtual machine and Lua with some C code.

The LuaJava authors have already done that work - you're better off using that than writing your own.