# What is Lua Scripting

Tags: android, lua

What is Lua Scripting? Where can I learn it? I want to develop an Android game using Lua, how do I start and is it possible to use Lua in android..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use lua scripts in a java android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994997/is-it-possible-to-use-lua-scripts-in-a-java-android-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) is a programming language.

You learn the language the same way you learn any programming language. I suggest you start by reading the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LearningLua).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994997/is-it-possible-to-use-lua-scripts-in-a-java-android-project) in regards to using it on Android.

Comment: I will upvote you once you fix "LUA" to "Lua" ;)

Comment: @ponzao - Nitpicker... You _can_ edit, you know.

Comment: I know I know, sorry about the nitpicking. But it is a very common typing error that annoys us Lua enthusiasts a lot and for that reason it is good to be visual imho.

Comment: @ponzao - My point is that there is an edit link on every answer - nothing is stopping you from clicking it an updating the post...

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK is a 2D game development tool for both iOS and Android that uses Lua:

http://www.anscamobile.com/

Comment: And don't forget Moai for same: http://getmoai.com/