# Alternative way to connect Lua and Java

Tags: java, lua, connect, luajava

I've been searching for this for hours now: I have a lua script with variables I'd like to add to a java program. Is there an other way than using luajava (which I tried to set up with no luck), or something like write to a text file than read from it with java?

What I want, is: run a lua thread and a java thread and read data from the lua thread and use it in the java thread.

Comment: How about tcp sockets? Or, running your Lua script in Java implementation of Lua?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113432/how-can-i-embed-lua-in-java

Comment: If you show what problems you had setting up luajava, you can get help setting that up.

Comment: no what i want, is: run a lua thread and a java thread and read data from the lua thread and use it in the java thread. I've installed luaJ I can run lua scripts with that thought I'm not sure I know what I'm doing. LuaJava: the problem was, that I couldn't find the VCVARS32.BAT, I installed msvc++, reinstalled it, I just could not get it work

Comment: @FerencDajka: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to connect Lua and Java is [jnlua](https://code.google.com/p/jnlua/).

In contrast to [LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/), it has [several advantages](https://code.google.com/p/jnlua/wiki/InterfacingWithJavaFromLua) - it handles Java arrays, provides specialized `__ipairs` and `__pairs` metamethods for `List` and `Map` derivates, `__tostring` using `toString()`, `__eq` using `equals()` and `__lt` when an object implements `Comparable`.

Note that jnlua 1.0 requires Lua 5.2, if you only have Lua 5.1 you have to use jnlua 0.9.