# How can programs make Lua(or python) interpreter execute statements provided by the program?

Tags: java, python, linux, lua

I am using Cent OS 7.

I want to write a program(written in Java or other languages) that can interact with Lua interpreter.
I hope that my program can feed statements to Lua interpreter, and get executed real-time, while previous variables are still available.

For example, my program feeds `a = 4; print(a);` to Lua interpreter `4` is printed on the screen. Then the program does other work. Later it feeds `n = 0; for i=1,4 do n = n + i; end; print(n);` to the interpreter, and `10` is printed on the screen.

Note: All I want is that Lua interpreter execute the statements when my program feeds it one, while keeping its previous status. My program does not need to access variables in Lua interpreter.

I tried calling Lua interpreter separately, but it doesn't work as expected.
Another solution is to record all previous statements, and run them before a new statement is going to run. But this is obviously not efficient.

Is there a easy way to do this? Such as just creating sub-process and making system calls?

Comment: I don't know specifically about the Lua interpreter, but if you can call it from the terminal, you can probably use the `subprocess` module to access it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is very broad, and not a specific programming problem. Also, you provide none of your research results, some searching and researching will give you more insights.

Comment: I will flag this as too broad. Is it immoral or a bad example if I answer a question which I am going to flag?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It seems that `subprocess.call` can not keep previous status, including variables.

Comment: @MartinNyolt I edit the problem to show what I have done. Perhaps you may think this a broad question, but it does stuck me. It's OK that you don't tell me the solution, but please tell me where I can get answered. Other people who asked a broad question would also his answer, and will not bother you on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is very broad (interpret Lua or Python, in any language), I can only give you some hints.

If you write in C or C++, you can use the Lua library directly. It probably allows you to execute Lua statements, make values in C visible to the Lua code, make C function available to the Lua code, and access values of the Lua code.

If you write in Java, you may either write a JNI wrapper for the Lua library, or use another Lua implementation. See [how can I embed lua in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2113432/1314743).

For other languages, you essentially have the same options: either use (if available) some other implementation in your favourite language, or find a way how you can access C library functions from your language. The latter is possible for most relevant programming languages.

For Python, the situation is similar. See, for example, [Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119696/1314743) and [Integrating Python With Other Languages](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages).

Comment: I know why you think the question is broad now. I hope I can achieve this by creating subprocess and make some system calls, which are irrelevant with the bridge between Lua and the language I use.

Comment: I have edited the problem so that it would not look so broad.

Comment: How does this answer not help you? I have outlined several choices for your problem and linked to a related question. All these solutions work for your problem of keeping the state.